# Weird results of sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances_argmin_min when computing euclidean distance

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, scipy

I'm implementing a customized version of the k-means algorithm for outlier detection. For this I need to assign data points to cluster centers as well as calculate the distance to the respective center. My data inputs are pandas Dataframes and I use sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances_argmin_min to quickly compute both distance and cluster label in the same step.

But when using metric='euclidean' as argument I'm experiencing weird results leading my algorithm to classify most points as outliers.
Please consider the following example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances_argmin_min
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
from scipy.spatial import distance
A = np.array([[3,3],
             [2,2]])
B = np.array([[1,1]])
pair_dist = pairwise_distances(A, B, metric='euclidean')
_, pair_dist_arg = pairwise_distances_argmin_min(A, B, metric='euclidean')
dist_euclid = [distance.euclidean(A[0,:], B), distance.euclidean(A[1,:], B)]
print('pairwise distances: ', pair_dist.flatten())
print('pairwise distances argmin: ', pair_dist_arg)
print('distance.euclidean: ', dist_euclid)
```

Output:

```
pairwise distances:  [2.82842712 1.41421356]
pairwise distances argmin:  [1.68179283 1.18920712]
distance.euclidean:  [2.8284271247461903, 1.4142135623730951]
```

Why am I experiencing different results for pairwise_distances and pairwise_distances_argmin_min when using euclidean distance'?
The results are identical for various other metrics I tried (canberra, cityblock, etc.) and oddly enough also for l2 (which is the same as euclidean).
It seems as pairwise_distances_argmin_min takes a square root too much or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have run into a bug in `pairwise_distances_argmin_min(..., metric='euclidean')`: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/12481/files

I get same result for all three calculations, using `sklearn 0.19.1`.

First check your sklearn version:

```
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__) # Or print sklearn.__version__ in Python 2.7
```

If it is 0.20.0 then you know it is probably this bug. This bug appears to be a [regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_regression) (i.e. it used to work correctly in previous versions), so it may be that you have a later version of `sklearn` than I do.

Updating `sklearn` to 0.20.1 (using `pip`, `conda`, or whatever package manager you use) should resolve the issue.

Comment: I was running sklearn 0.20.0.
After updating with conda to 0.20.1 the bug is gone, thank you very much for the help!