# NameError: name 'pairwise_distances_argmin' is not defined

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, nameerror

Upon running this code:

```
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()

from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
X, y_true = make_blobs(n_samples = 300, centers= 4, cluster_std =0.60,random_state = 0)
plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], s=50)

labels = pairwise_distances_argmin(X, centres)
```

I am getting a NameError

> "name 'pairwise_distances_argmin' is not defined"

What may be the possible reasons for it.

Please note that I am relatively new to this field, elaborated answers are most welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Have searched Stack overflow and unsuccessfully try solutions suggested on these pages:

1. [Weird results of sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances_argmin_min when computing euclidean distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53723798/weird-results-of-sklearn-metrics-pairwise-distances-argmin-min-when-computing-eu)
2. [NameError: name 'sklearn' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57364290/nameerror-name-sklearn-is-not-defined)

Comment: Where do you believe the name is defined?  There is certainly no definition visible in the code you posted.  There appears to be something with that name in `sklearn.metrics`, but you'd have to actually `import` it for the name to be available to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wish to use the
[pairwise_distances_argmin](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances_argmin.html)
function.

You're going to have to import it:

```
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances_argmin
```